# Can shootouts happen in the town square?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

The rules are a bit confusing about where shootouts can happen. All of the examples, both in the Welcome to Gomorra tutorial and in the rulebook, show shootouts happening in order to contest control over a deed card. The rules consistently mention the "location" that a shootout is occurring, but don't seem to ever define what counts a location. Is it just deeds or does the town square count as well?

So can shootouts occur in the town square?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have Shoot-Outs in Town Square.

On page 18:

> As a Noon play, one of your unbooted dudes can choose a dude controlled by another player at the same location, and call out that dude (challenge that dude to a shootout). This doesn’t boot your dude, and so as long as your dude stays unbooted, they can call out an opposing dude each and every time it’s your turn to make a play."

And on page 12 it states:

> There are three types of in-town locations. Each deed is its own location. Each outfit’s home is a location (with a few special rules). And the area in the middle of the table is a location called the town square.

Shootouts happen when dudes are at the same location and there are three types of in-town locations, one of which is the town square.